# how do you reference server logins from a visual Studio database project?

Tags: database-projects, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a way to move all our SQL Server databases (on one server) into source control.

I tried creating a solution, and then adding VS database projects to the solution that correspond to the SQL Server databases.

As I was creating the projects (via importing existing databases) I chose to import security objects.

These security objects are users that need to reference logins of some kind. i.e. in a database project I have a folder `Security` with the SQL script: `CREATE USER xxx`. The VS debugger underlines this in red and warns me:

> SQL71501: User: xxx has an unresolved reference to Login xxx.

To fix this I tried creating a new project called `SERVER`, in which I would include server-related SQL files.

- How do I reference this new project from the other database project?

Comment: This answer give few suggestion with similar issue you are having.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107556/unresolved-reference-to-user-after-importing-as-a-vs-db-project

Answer (score 3):

Right click on references in your SSDT project. Click on Add Database reference.

[image]

Fill out the database reference information here. I bring in the server I am connecting to as a dacpac object, then reference it as a project in the current solution. Seems to work best for me.

EDIT: I just tested using a database project in the same solution as well and it resolved the references correctly.

[image]
Edit 2: Why this works - Projects within a VS solution do not "talk" to each other, by default. In the real world, servers and databases do "reference" each other. What we are doing here is explicitly making that connection, because the scope of a SSDT project can only be one database. Once you add the SSDT project and sync all the objects, including the security, you need to add that project as a reference in order for it "see" the database objects at the server level.

Comment: Can you use this to maintain logins and users, without the broken dependencies that Zach Smith observed?

Comment: Yah, that's why I did the dacpacs. It was way to annoying to have all those login and user broken dependencies when I tried to bring our stuff under source control for the first time.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades what didn't you like about this solution? I actually just had a new login reference issue pop up, and solved it with the method I posted.

Comment: Frankly?  I honestly don't see that it addresses the issue (that I'm trying to solve) at all.  There's nothing here about logins or users.  It seems to be a method of adding a database to a project, which is nice and all but I'm interested in having users which share a login across multiple databases.

Comment: OK, I've been poking around with this some more, and I think I see how it's supposed to help.  If you'd like to explain that in your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades let me know if that is good enough. I haven't had my coffee yet.